# Enable and disable Renderer or Canvas not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, renderer, hololens

Every 5 seconds I need to take a photo and display it in the world. That part is working fine.
Once a photo is taken it need to disappear 1 second after. That's where I'm stuck.
I've gotten it to disappear but then I cant get the new picture to reappear when its function is called again.

Any ideas?

I've tried:

```
m_CanvasRenderer.enabled = false;
m_CanvasRenderer.enabled = true;
m_Canvas = null;
m_Canvas.setActive(false);
m_Canvas.setActive(true);
```

With no luck

```
    public class PhotoCaptureExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    GestureRecognizer m_GestureRecognizer;
    GameObject m_Canvas = null;
    Renderer m_CanvasRenderer = null;
    PhotoCapture m_PhotoCaptureObj;
    CameraParameters m_CameraParameters;
    bool m_CapturingPhoto = false;
    Texture2D m_Texture = null;

    void Start()
    {
        Initialize();
        InvokeRepeating("TakePhoto", 5.0f, 5.0f);
        //StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
    }

void TakePhoto()
    {
        if (m_CapturingPhoto)
        {
            return;
        }
        m_CapturingPhoto = true;
        m_PhotoCaptureObj.TakePhotoAsync(OnPhotoCaptured);
    }

    void OnPhotoCaptured(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
    {
       // m_CanvasRenderer.enabled = true;

        if (m_Canvas == null)
        {

            m_Canvas = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
            m_Canvas.name = "PhotoCaptureCanvas";
            m_CanvasRenderer = m_Canvas.GetComponent<Renderer>() as Renderer;
            m_CanvasRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("AR/HolographicImageBlend"));
        }

        Matrix4x4 cameraToWorldMatrix;
        photoCaptureFrame.TryGetCameraToWorldMatrix(out cameraToWorldMatrix);
        Matrix4x4 worldToCameraMatrix = cameraToWorldMatrix.inverse;

        Matrix4x4 projectionMatrix;
        photoCaptureFrame.TryGetProjectionMatrix(out projectionMatrix);

        photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(m_Texture);
        m_Texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;

        m_CanvasRenderer.sharedMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", m_Texture);
        m_CanvasRenderer.sharedMaterial.SetMatrix("_WorldToCameraMatrix", worldToCameraMatrix);
        m_CanvasRenderer.sharedMaterial.SetMatrix("_CameraProjectionMatrix", projectionMatrix);
        m_CanvasRenderer.sharedMaterial.SetFloat("_VignetteScale", 1.0f);

        // Position the canvas object slightly in front
        // of the real world web camera.
        Vector3 position = cameraToWorldMatrix.GetColumn(3) - cameraToWorldMatrix.GetColumn(2);

        // Rotate the canvas object so that it faces the user.
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-cameraToWorldMatrix.GetColumn(2), cameraToWorldMatrix.GetColumn(1));

        m_Canvas.transform.position = position;
        m_Canvas.transform.rotation = rotation;

        m_CapturingPhoto = false;

        float counter = 0; float target = 1;
        while (counter < target)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        // m_CanvasRenderer.enabled = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: You could create an animation that makes your object slowly dissapear (A attribute of color going from current value to 0), and another one which makes it appear again, and play them when needed.

Comment: What would I animate in this case? The m_Canvas or the m_CanvasRenderer? The image gets added to the m_CanvasRenderer.

Comment: m_Canvas and m_CanvasRenderer do not have an alpha attribute